# Largest PhD programs in mathematics

Tags: graduate-school, mathematics

I'll be applying to graduate schools in the fall but so far don't have any real clue what area I want to focus on. As such, I hope to attend a very large math graduate program with a lot of varied research going on so that there are many avenues I can explore. I also worry that if I attend a small or midsize graduate school, I may come to find out that my true passion is in an topic for which there are no suitable advisers. I also think I'd fit in *much* better in a larger department.

I'm interested in a list of PhD math programs by number of students. So I've done some googling, but I can't find any relavant results. **What are the largest math graduate programs in the US?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, the state universities have much larger programs. There is a very strong correlation between the size of the school, the size of the math department, and the size of the math graduate program. For example, Ohio State has over 60 000 students over all their campuses and if I remember correctly, nearly 200 grad students in math and faculty in nearly every area. Look up the largest universities, and they will be very likely to have the largest programs.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, I'll look into this. It didn't occur to me that there would be such a strong correlation.

Comment: @MajoringInUndecided to understand why there is such a strong correlation, note the number of TAs and faculty required to teach calculus to over 5,000 students each year!

Answer (score 11):

The AMS has [this help](http://www.ams.org/programs/students/findgradprograms/findgradprograms) for those searching graduate schools.
For "size" you can use the statistic "Number of PhDs awarded in the last 3 years" which is included.  For example, I found that the champion was U.C.Berkeley, with 83 PhDs

Answer (score 2):

As has been pointed out by Johanna, there is a strong correlation between the size of a university and the size of the math department (because basically every student in a university has to take some kind of math course), and by consequence with the size of the graduate program. But the better correlation is actually between the size of the *engineering program of a university* and the size of its math departments because engineering students have to take *multiple* math courses.

This explains why universities such as Ohio State, Michigan State, Texas A&M, etc, have such large math departments -- they are very large engineering schools. A general rule of thumb is that in most states, the University of X has a larger liberal arts program and a smaller engineering program, whereas the X State University has it reverse (due to their heritage as land grant universities). The names of the X State University are not always uniform (as in the case of Texas A&M, Virginia Tech, Georgia Tech) but often are (in the cases of Ohio, Michigan, Colorado, Oklahoma, for example).

Comment: This seems misguided.  For instance, the University of Michigan's math department is not smaller than Michigan State's, the University of Texas's math department is not smaller than Texas A&M's, etc.

Comment: Similarly, University of Colorado has larger a Math (and Applied Math) program than Colorado State University. Similarly for Oklahoma, California, etc.

Comment: Hm. The University of Texas math department has only about 2/3 the number of TT faculty than Texas A&M's math department. It is true that the number of graduate students is roughly the same. I will not try to verify the numbers for the other states and take your words at it.

Comment: Besides what others have mentioned many schools named "The university of X" are in fact land grant and many that are X state university are not. For example University of California and University of Florida and University of Georgia.  "The university of Ohio" doesn't even exist so how is Ohio an example of anything you mention?

Comment: @WetLabStudent There is an Ohio University: http://www.ohio.edu/

Comment: The OP doesn't specify if they are interested in pure or applied mathematics; if pure, then I think your statement is not a very useful generalization.  Often times having a large engineering program will direct resources away from pure math (compare Oregon and Oregon State, for example, or UVA and Virginia Tech, or Michigan and Michigan State).

Comment: Also, the naming things are just too idiosyncratic to generalize.  There is a "Virginia State."  It's a historically black university, as several of the X State U's in the south (Tennessee State, Alabama State) are.  There's also "Virginia Commonwealth," (officially we're the Commonwealth of Virginia, not the State of Virginia) which is actually the biggest public school in the state.

Comment: @BenWebster Ohio University does not equal University of Ohio. The answer specifically said "University of X" formula and that Ohio followed the formula.

Comment: Oh, dear, I've really stepped into a wasp nest here :-) To respond to @BenWebster , that also doesn't seem to be a useful criterion. True, Virginia Tech is an almost completely applied department at a university with a big engineering school. On the other hand, my own department at Texas A&M is 2/3 pure and at most 10% interdisciplinary, despite the fact that we have a big engineering school. It all makes no sense :-)

Comment: I guess my point is just that the mistake is expecting a pattern; having a big engineering school can drive the resources to have a big math department. So can just having a big undergraduate population.  So can having an administration that's willing to invest in the math department.  I think the premise of the question is a little silly, but so is an answer beyond just doing a little investigation of the individual schools.  The sample size is small enough that you'll never know if you're overfitting (especially since none of us seem to have the real data at the ready).